# Redirect paths with .htaccess from main domain to subdomain - multisite installation

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal

I have my drupal setup at www.my-main-domain.com,
i have drupal  multisite installation at subdomain.my-main-domain.com

I want to redirect all:

> www.my-main-domain.com/user , www.my-main-domain.com/users, 
>   www.my-main-domain.com/user/*

paths to my subdomain subdomain:

> my-main-domain.com/user , subdomain.my-main-domain.com/users,
>   subdomain.my-main-domain.com/*

respectively.

I'm writing following in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteBase / 
RedirectMatch 301 ^/users/(.*)$ http://subdomain.my-main-domain.com/users/$1
RedirectMatch 301 ^/user/(.*)$ http://subdomain.my-main-domain.com/user/$1
RedirectMatch 301 ^/users$ http://subdomain.my-main-domain.com/users
RedirectMatch 301 ^/user$ http://subdomain.my-main-domain.com/user
```

But it redirects to subdomain but in continues loop and hence ends with blank display.

Please note that it's multisite installation with common root .htaccess file.
I have tried path redirect drupal module but its not supporting internal paths redirection saying paths already in use.

Please help. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mod_rewrite` instead to control the host name in rewrite condition.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-main-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(users?)(/.*)?$ http://subdomain.my-main-domain.com/$1$2 [L,R=301,NC]
```

**PS: Also note that your 4 rules can be combined into one as shown above.**

Comment: Only thing i'm not getting how it's handling redirect for /user where we only matching /users in above rule. Can you please explain?

Comment: Actually I have made `s` optional after `/user` by using regex `users?` that is why it matches both `/user` and `/users`.